# POST request JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have this ajax script but I want to convert it to PHP.

This my Json body:

```
{
"DateTime": "2016-10-25T11:09:5702:00", 
"AlarmType": "Rmn", 
"DespatchId": Uniquid from alarm center, 
"Latitude": 2.1,
"Longitude": 3.1
}
```

Ajax jQuery

```
$.ajax({url: '/ api/Alarm/AlarmInLocation,
type: 'post',
datatype: 'json',
data: Payload,
beforeSend: function(request)
{   request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                         },
 success: function(response) {
          var d = JSON.stringify(response);
} });
```

I tried in this way, but does not work, it responde DIE:

```
// The data to send to the API
    $postData = array('DateTime' => '2016-10-25T11:09:5702:00',
                      'AlarmType' => 'Rmn',
                      'DespatchId' => '1234',
                      'Latitude' => '2.1',
                      'Longitude' => '3.1'
                     );

                    // Create the context for the request
                    $context_alarm = stream_context_create(array(
                    'http' => array(
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'header' => "Authorization: {$authToken}\r\n".
                    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
                    'content' => json_encode($postData)
                    )
                    ));

    $response_alarm = file_get_contents('https://myapi.com/api/Alarm/AlarmInLocation', false, $context_alarm); 

    // Check for errors

    if($response_alarm === FALSE){
                            die('Error Get Response Alarm');
                            }
```

Comment: You miss a ' in your ajax url.

Comment: I don't think you have constructed the options correctly. See the example here of how to POST data using these methods. http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php . You should use a tool like Fiddler to monitor the HTTP traffic and check whether your request is constructed correctly. You'll also see more detail of the HTTP response from the remote server. Basically you just need to debug it properly, and read the documentation in full.